# libclang python binding don't return any of fixits

Tags: python, libclang

I want to dump diagnostics and fixits from translation unit (tu). But below code don't works.

```
def dump_fixits():
    """Return diagnostics with fixits of translation unit."""
    result = []
    for diag in tu.diagnostics:
        diag_fixits = [repr(it) for it in diag.fixits]
        location = diag.location
        file = "" if location.file is None else location.file.name
        result.append((file + ":"
                       + str(location.line) + ":"
                       + str(location.column) + ": "
                       + severity_map[diag.severity] + ": "
                       + diag.spelling,
                       diag_fixits))
    return result
```

(I'm using llvm 3.4)

I noticed `conf.lib.clang_getDiagnosticNumFixIts()` returns `0` everytime.

Is there any of solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood for fixit. I thought fixit can get spell miss but it isn't. Close this question. Thank you.